# Is there a Theta-Method Numerical Scheme for General Semilinear Parabolic Partial Differential Equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

Is there an analogue of the $\theta$-method for a general semilinear parabolic partial differential equation
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = a(x, t) \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}} + b(x, t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + c(x, t)u(x,t) + d(x,t)?
$$